# Google Analytics API - ga:day not showing correct data

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am trying to pull Session data by day for particular segments.  I am trying to do this with the script below.

However, when I use ga:day as a dimension, the sessions returned are much lower than what they are in the Google Analytics user interface.

Also, the results.get(date) item is returning "None" (if I give a range of dates, it still only comes up with one session number).

What am I not seeing?

```
def get_segment_sessions(service, profile_id, segment_id):

    return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      segment='gaid::' + segment_id,
      dimensions='ga:day',
      start_date='2017-04-14',
      end_date='2017-04-14',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()

def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
    print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
    print 'Date: %s' % results.get('date') + ' Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

  else:
    print 'No results found'

def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Use the developer console and replace the values with your
  # service account email and relative location of your key file.
  service_account_email = '**********'
  key_file_location = '********'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(get_results(service, profile))
  get_segments(service)

  #print odd video sessions
  print_results(get_segment_sessions(service, profile, '*********'))

  #print even video sessions
  print_results(get_segment_sessions(service, profile, '********'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth checking if the setup of your segments in GA - if you want to pull session data from them ensure they are set to session level, rather than user level, as this may be impacting your data when you try and match it back to GA reports.

Comment: Where do I change that?

Comment: When you edit your segment in GA there's a drop down in the top left corner to select 'user' or 'session' level.